# How can I save a complex object from an external DLL?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a complex object from an external DLL (*I can't change the code of this object*).

Take this class as an example, This class has no id and contains other complex classes.

```
public class Car : IVehicle
{
    public IWheel Wheel { get; set; }
    public IEngine Engine { get; set; }
    public Car(IWheel wheel, IEngine engine)
    {
        Wheel = wheel;
        Engine = engine;
    }
}
```

How can I save this object using Entity Framework Code First ?

Comment: You can't save it directly, you will have to map it to an equivalent entity class that your DbContext knows about.

Comment: I correctly understood that I should make CarDTO in repository and copy properties from Car to CarDTO with convertation and save CarDTO without Car and this method there is no alternative?

Comment: why do you insist on using this class from a 3rd party assembly? even if it was possible it would be wrong, to allow creating database objects based on types you can't control.

Comment: I am developing an application based on third-party libraries, third-party libraries contain several thousands classes, and I can't move it to my project, but for my application I need to save the state of several third-party classes.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately EntityFramework does not support entities without primary keys other than complex types.

However you don't necessarily need to create DTOs and conversions from the objects of the third part library to these DTOs, it is enough to create a subclass such as CarEntity then add an Id property to it:

```
class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class CarEntity : Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework will map this hierarchy correctly to one table, see the required migration step:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.CarEntities",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Name = c.String(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

This way you can store these entities with minimal additional work and reuse them in the Third party library's functions which will expect Car types as input etc.